# Convert Date From String To Datetime in spark scala

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, datetime

I have that format of date Tue Dec 31 07:14:22 +0000 2013 in string and I need to convert it to Date object where the timestamp field is to be indexed in scala spark

Comment: if you could  add some sample data that would have been great.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by splitting the string column by space and converting that column to array type and then creating a new string column with any of the supported date format.

```
//Creating sample data
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq(("Tue Dec 31 07:14:22 +0000 2013"),("Thu Dec 09 09:14:42 +0000 2017")).toDF("DateString")
//creating new column of type array from string column
val df1 = df.withColumn("DateArray", split($"DateString", " "))
//Getting the required elements from the array column and combining them to get the date
val df2 = df1.withColumn("DateTime" , concat($"DateArray".getItem(5), lit("-"), $"DateArray".getItem(1), lit("-"),$"DateArray".getItem(2))).withColumn("Date",to_date($"DateTime","yyyy-MMM-dd"))
//Using display to show the content of the dataframe. you can also use .show method.
display(df2)
```

You can drop the columns that you don't require as per your output requirement.

you can see the output as below :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

to create an index for dates:

```
collection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("date_column"))
```